# Three ways to get machine architecture

Tags: shell, command-line, architecture, cpu-architecture

Two very common ways of getting the machine architecture are these:

`uname -m`
and
`arch`.

They both print things like `x86_64`.

But I remember there is a third way to do that, but I can't remember what it was. I saw it some sort of Makefile-like script once, and for the love of god, I can't recall what it was.

Does anyone remember what it was, and perhaps remember its use in build scripts?

Thanks in advance -- this is kinda driving me a little crazy, tbh...

Comment: `getconf LONG_BIT`? You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480194/how-to-find-a-base-architecture-inside-makefile)

Comment: There are many tools, that may or may not be installed altready in your Linux distro, for example `lshw`, `inxi`, `hardinfo`, `neofetch`. In Ubuntu and Debian you can download the [`system-info`](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/) script by the Ubuntu Forums which tries to use built-in tools, so that the user needs no direct internet connection (but can install the script for example via a USB pendrive).

Comment: On MacOS at least, there is a command `machine` which for me prints `x86_64h`

Answer (score 1):

`$ cat /proc/cpuinfo`
`$ lscpu` These give similar info in different formats and include architecture details like 32b mode memory address size byte order, specific cpu model and the available instruction-set extensions that can be used for optimized compiling(eg sse4_2 or aes)
Pipe into `grep` if desired.

`$ lstopo` will create either a graphical map of your machine or an ascii tree with various verboseness options. Shows physical and logical cores, cache levels(with core association and either instruction or data if dedicated.), main memory including NUMA layout, and items connected through the PCI[e] bus such as sata drives, add-in cards, and ethernet. Mine is also showing some graphics card details like "Co-Processor openCL 16 compute units" and the graphics card memory.
Though it doesn't go into the finest details like if a cache level uses an inclusive or exclusive policy.

Comment: +1 for `lstopo` didn't know that one, but my question was primarily concerning an architecture string result, used in shellscripting, etc.